# How to make all layers seamless in a same way?

Tags: layers, texture, maps

Let's say I have created one photoshop document with 3 layers. (visible in the image I posted).

I am going to use these maps in a 3d-modeling program, so it is very important that I need to have these files to be seamless in the exactly similar way.

I know that I can use the "Offset" filter and then "clone stamp tool" to make one image to be a seamless pattern, but the problem with that is that I need to have all the layers **exactly** similar way to be seamless. Otherwise, the texture won't work. With manual clone stamping, I cannot find it be possible. So is there someone who knows how this can be achieved?

[image]

Here is also an image of how these are being used. You can see the seam in the render quite clearly in the middle of the rendering viewport editor. [image]

Comment: Why do you not create at first the grey version as a tileable pattern and process then the colored versions from the result?

Comment: Because the process of making this kind of images don't work like that. If I, for example, do camera mapping/photogrammetry, the first image is the cluster of photos from which I have to generate the other images.

Comment: Am I right that the images are compositionally the same to begin with?

Comment: Yes, the composition of the images is similar in all of those, they just have different colors.

Comment: The source maps have actually been done in 3d Because generating the depth map or normal map out of a image is not really possible unless you have a VERY well equipped photographic lab for this purpose at your disposal. But yes you can also tile it by masking isntead of cloning which would keep multiple separate source images the same. But then making the 3d tileable is pretty easy.

Comment: You're right. I generated this in 3D-program, but photogrammetry is still all the time more and more common way to generate textures. And you don't necessarily need a studio for that. (it can help a lot tho) But just a camera and time to take lots and lots of photos will also do the job.

Comment: @Artturi photogrametry will not work very well with this intricate images quite that well. Granted it works because its a diffuse surface. OTOH a 3d depth camera does not cost more than 300 $. Also blending works ok for depth but not so much for the normal map

Comment: Tbh for me, it's ok if it works or if it does not work. I am not here because of that. Here anyway is some random tutorial I found about photogrammetry if you're interested of the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGyoM3tujlc

Comment: There is also free software that can construct 3d files from images very well.

Comment: @Artturi yeah ive used photogrammetry on projects before. I kind of stopped since the results suck, and i can get way better results with a kinect like point cloud setup or dedicated 3d scanner. Both of which i have many of in my office (and yeah i have a dedicated photo studio on the next floor too)

Comment: Okay, now you made me interested. There are not too many people here in Finland who are working with this kind of things. :)

 And I agree that with dedicated devices it, of course, works better, but I am still quite sure also that in some projects it is very much ok to use just the camera. I have seen people doing with some simple gear nice things.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply the same pattern-making process to a number of similar images then all you need to do is make your edits non-destructively to smart objects; you can then swap out the smart object's content to each original image.

Mostly this just means duplicating layers and using masks instead of clone-stamping.

An example. Take this un-repeating image...

[image]

I place it in Photoshop as a linked smart object. I then offset it both horizontally and vertically (if you're going to be manually masking areas than you *may* want to create the offset manually by duplicating the layer and moving/masking as appropriate):

[image]

I then cover the "seams" by duplicating the smart object and isolating specific bricks:

[image]

"Applying" the process to a similar image is then as simple as swapping the contents of the smart object:

[image]

I'd note that the hardest part of making a repeating pattern from your image is the image itself; with a more uniform texture (e.g. paper, fabric) clone-stamping or blending is easy enough. But your image is made up of distinct objects so you need to give *a lot* more time and attention to covering the "seams". Unfortunately the only solution to that is spending the time doing it manually; as such my example is very quick and crude.

Comment: I'd like to see the end result of this – lots and lots of Lego! :)

Comment: Endless lego! My house would be a happier place

Comment: Thank you. If I cannot find some faster process later, I will start using this. :)

Comment: I learned that I can do the clone stamping better in Affinity Photo which supports clone stamping multiple layers simultaneously, so I think I will continue this project in that software instead.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue and I have 3 workarounds for you (only 1 in Photoshop). The last one can take on the most complicate clone stamp jobs and is the closest to a perfect solution.

### Photoshop: Record Action(s)

Record the Photoshop Clone Stamp strokes into an action with "Tool Recording" on:

[image]
[image]

This is for simpler actions. If the you have complicate/multiple stamping going on, you may mess up with one stroke recording and then the whole action is trashed.

### Substance Designer: Multi Clone Patch + Smart Auto Tile

The "Multi Clone Patch" node in Substance Designer can apply the same clone to every input, but this is not as ideal when you want to get into heavy editing/clone stamping on multiple layers or files. The "Smart Auto Tile" currently can only do so much, it may not be ideal on some complicate patterns.

### After Effects: Clone Stamp tool + Offset filter

After Effects can apply clone stamp to a video layer, so you can import your image files as an image sequence layer, do the clone, and then render it into individual frames. Here are the steps in After Effects:

1. Import multiple image files as an image sequence layer.
2. Apply an offset filter to offset the seams to the center of the layer:

[image]

3. Use (multiple) Clone Stamp to eliminate any imperfections & seams:

[image]

4. Apply another offset filter to reverse the first offset.
5. Render the layer into image sequences (individual image files), preferably in lossless formats.
6. Done!